# Acquire multiple locks with shared timeout

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have multiple objects which I want to lock with `Monitor.TryEnter` simultaneously with a one single timeout. If I lock them consequentially later objects can't start entering lock until previous are locked which leads to that later objects have less timeout so less chance to be successfully locked:

```
Monitor.TryEnter(A, 10000);
Monitor.TryEnter(B, 10000 - passedA); // smaller timeout
Monitor.TryEnter(C, 10000 - passedAB); // even smaller timeout
```

Can I make them all start locking at the same time?

I want something like `Monitor.TryEnterMany(new[] {A, B, C}, 10000)`.

I think I could use `AutoResetEvent` instead of locking so to "enter" locks I would call `WaitAll` on all events and to "release" I would call `Set` on each of them. Do you think it's a good solution?

Comment: Since you have an idea of how to solve the problem, what happened when you tried that?

Comment: @Servy I got this idea just after posting the question) I think it will work but I'm not sure whether it's good enough in terms of performance so may be there is a better solution.

Comment: Then try it out and see if it will work or not.

Comment: @Servy I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Mutex` instead of `AutoResetEvent`:

```
        Mutex A = new Mutex(), B = new Mutex(), C = new Mutex();
        Mutex[] waitHandles = new[] { A, B, C };
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles, 10000);
        // Do stuff.
        foreach(Mutex mutex in waitHandles)
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
```

Comment: Is there any difference except syntactical?

Comment: Conceptually, Mutexes are exactly the same as locks.  AutoResetEvents can be used for a variety of purposes.  So by using a Mutex you are telling the reader that you are using locks.  If you use an AutoResetEvent, the reader still has to guess at how the event might be used.  What's more, AutoResetEvents will, under race conditions, behave in ways that I can't guarantee is exactly like a lock.  See the scary note at the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The scary note says that two "Set" calls may release only 1 waiting thread (not 2) which doesn't look like a problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I could use AutoResetEvent instead of locking so to "enter"
>   locks I would call WaitAll on all events and to "release" I would call
>   Set on each of them.

So this looks working, here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // checks that WaitAll doesn't reset first event on timeout
            var ev1 = new AutoResetEvent(true);
            var ev2 = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(new [] { ev1, ev2}, 1000);
            ev1.WaitOne();

            int counter = 0;
            var m = new MyMonitor();
            var m2 = new MyMonitor();
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(
                x => Task.Run(
                    () =>
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
                        {
                            if (!MyMonitor.TryAcquireMany(100000, m, m2)) throw new TimeoutException();
                            counter++;
                            m.Release();
                            m2.Release();
                        }
                    })).ToArray();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            Console.WriteLine(counter + " should be " + (1000 * 1000));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class MyMonitor
    {
        readonly AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent(true);

        public static bool TryAcquireMany(int timeout, params MyMonitor[] monitors)
        {
            return WaitHandle.WaitAll(monitors.Select(x => (WaitHandle)x._event).ToArray(), timeout);
        }

        public bool TryAcquire(int timeout)
        {
            return _event.WaitOne(timeout);
        }

        public void Release()
        {
            _event.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

It's still not tested enough and of course it doesn't support reentrance. Do you think it's good in terms of performance?